# Sharing state across React router v6 routes using Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

Looking through old tutorials it seems like React Router v5 had support for sharing state across different routes using the context API but I can't find anything on a similar usage for Router v6.

### React Router v5 Implementation of what I am trying to do:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
 return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about/">About</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <UserContext.Provider value={user,setUser}>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
          <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

and then you can access the state using the `useContext` hook

```
const {value, setValue} = useContext(UserContext);
```

### v6 Implementation

When attempting to use this implementation with v6 (exchanging the degraded v5 components for the new v6 ones) you will run into errors because you can only have `<Route>` components as children in a router.

**Is it possible to share state with a global context store across React Router V6 routes?**

Below is my attempt at V6 implementation:

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("initial state");

  return (
    <>
      <Header props={(key, setKey)} />
      <DataContext.Provider value={(value, setValue)}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/configuration" element={<Configuration />} />
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
```

**App.js different Approach**

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState("initial state");

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={(value, setValue)}>
      <Header props={(key, setKey)} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/configuration" element={<Configuration />} />
      </Routes>
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The issue with this solution is the state is still not updated globally when changed in one of the routes.
**For example** in `/dashboard` if I change value using `setValue` then it will reflect the changes in `/dashboard` but if I navigate to `/configuration` or refresh `value` will have reverted to original `value`, "initial state" in this case. (This is also the effect if I make a function in `App.js` which will use `setValue` and I pass the function to Provider instead)

I am sure that I could use React Redux to solve this problem but its really just one or two pieces of data that I need shared between routes - seems like overkill to implement all of the required redux boilerplate etc. and seems like a common use case that context should support.

Comment: I don't really understand what the issue is. Any React context has nothing to do with routing/navigation. Your second `App.js` approach appears correct, i.e. you've wrapped the components that consume the context value and you've correctly wrapped the `Route` components in the `Routes` component. What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, I have added a short example and better description to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Your "App.js different Approach" should still work. Have you included all relevant code in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its simple you need to use `Router` inside your `DataProvider`.

#### index.js

```js
// import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### app.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
// .....
// .....
// .....
 const [value, setValue] = useState("initial state");

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={(value, setValue)}>
      <Header props={(key, setKey)} />
      <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/configuration" element={<Configuration />} />
      </Routes>
      </Router>
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Also make sure you are using the `Link` of router to navigate to different pages. Using any other thing 'a' tag, etc. that refreshes the page will reset the `context`.

Comment: With the solution given the state is still not updated globally when changed in one of the routes. 
For example in /dashboard if I change `value` using `setValue` then it will reflect the changes in /dashboard but if I navigate to /configuration or refresh `value` will have reverted to original value. (This is also the effect if I make a function in App.js which will use setValue and I pass the function to Provider instead)

Comment: How are you navigating to different route? if you are using `a` tag or anything that requires reloading like `window.location = '/home'` then the problem lies there.

Comment: This was the issue ^ I was not using the router `Link` component I was using a bootstrap `Nav.Link` component. Thank you for the help - A full example of the React Router code that helped me re-factor can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/basic?file=src/App.tsx

Comment: Update this to the answer.

Comment: This is fine if you want to wrap ALL of your routes in the DataContext, but what if you only want to wrap the Context around some nested routes?

Comment: grayson, I searched and found out this comment on Reddit that helps to clarify how to wrap a context provider around a few routes:

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/uxvfvj/comment/ia0g5mx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

In short, you should put your context provider inside a component that uses either Outlet or useOutlet from React Router. Then, use the component as the element of a Route, which is the parent Route of the few and only routes you want the context to be available.

Comment: This might help->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764023/how-do-i-wrap-2-routes-with-a-context-in-react-router-v6

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above are accurate but you need to make a tiny little change if you are using **RouterProvider in react-router-dom-v6** and have defined your routes inside a **RouterProvider** like `<RouterProvider router={router} />`, wrap your RouterProvider inside your ContextProvider to make the context accessible.

I hope the code below clarifies what I am suggesting.

#### App.jsx

```
import { 
Route, 
Link, 
Routes, 
createBrowserRouter, 
createRoutesFromElements, 
RouterProvider 
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './Components/context/AuthContext';
....
import PrivateRoute from './Components/utils/PrivateRoute';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
      .... other Routes
     )
)

function App() {
  


  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

I made a separate module for Context just to keep the App.jsx clean.

#### AuthContext.jsx

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { axiosInstance } from "../Hooks/AxiosInst";


const AuthContext = createContext()


export default AuthContext;


export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

const [authToken, setToken] = useState(null)
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

const authLogin = async () //....
  

let contextData = {
    user: user,
    login:authLogin
}

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
}
```