# React router: Redirected on left-click but not on right-click

Tags: react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

**The problem**:
Clicking a link to `/username` from `/profile`, redirects to `/profile`. This is only wanted if `/currentUser.username`. When the same link is clicked from other endpoints, it does not redirect. Also, if right-clicking --> *open in new tab*, it does not redirect.

**What is causing the redirect and how do I avoid it?**

**Explanation**
`/profile` shows the currently logged in user's profile page and `/username` shows another user's profile. If the currently logged in user goes to `/currentUser.username` they will be redirected to `/profile`.

Both endpoints render the same `<Profile />` component. The content depends on whether the current user is `visitor` or not.

React context API manages state for `<Profile />`.

**Code**
The context provider checks if current user is a visitor:

```
export const ProfileProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [visitor, setVisitor] = useState(null);
  const { username } = useParams();
  const user = useSelector(selectCurrentUser); // currentUser

  console.log('username: ', username) // prints username in initial render.
  console.log(visitor); // prints false in initial render. Why?     

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect visitor: ', visitor) // prints false in initial render.
    setVisitor(username ? username !== user.username : false);
  }, [username, user.username]);

  // Omit code for brevity
};
```

In `<Profile />` I Have:

```
export const Profile = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {username, visitor} = useContext(ProfileContext);

  // navigate to ('/profile') if user is looking at their own profile. 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (visitor === false && username) {
      navigate('/profile');
    }
  }, [visitor, navigate, username]);

  // Omit code for brevity
}
```

And the link is in the header, which can be clicked from any endpoint:

```
<Link to={`/${user.username}`}></Link>
```

Where `user !== currentUser`.

Log statements:

```
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  qqqqqq0.6122198309846412
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:38 useEffect visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  qqqqqq0.6122198309846412
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  true
ProfileProvider.jsx:38 useEffect visitor:  true
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  true
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
ProfileProvider.jsx:19 username:  undefined
ProfileProvider.jsx:20 visitor:  false
```

Edit: Rephrased the problem.

Comment: Right-clicks aren't generally used to do the same things as left-clicks. I certainly wouldn't expect right-clicking on a link to navigate anywhere, so I'd say this is expected behavior. Other than this, it's not clear what you are saying is an issue or what you are asking for help with. Can you clarify what any issue is?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation isn't clear to you. What I mean is right-click --> open in new tab works fine and so does left-clicking on the link from all endpoints besides /profile. 
When I click the link from /profile to /<username> I'm redirected back to /profile for some reason. 
I will clarify in OP as well.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live along with exact reproduction steps?

Comment: Will this work?
https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-issue-wrypp5?file=/src/Profile.jsx
Very simplified but it reproduces the issue I believe.
From root/home we can click a link to navigate to /user2 without being redirected. If we click the same link while on profile, we are redirected back to /profile.

Comment: I think I see what is happening, but I'd like to understand better what you are wanting the expected behavior to be? When a user navigates from `"/profile/*"` to `"/:username/*"` what are you expecting to occur? Also, do you *want* two ***separate*** `ProfileProvider` contexts, or do you want a single profile context for the entire app?

Comment: I only want one ProfileProvider context.

The expected behavior is when you click the link from `/profile` you navigate to `/:username ` without being redirected (unlesss username === currentUser.username). Same behavior as when clicking the link from anywhere else.

Comment: I guess I'm getting lost between your code and what you are describing here. Click *what* link from `"/profile"` to navigate to `"/username"`, the links rendered by `App`? What are "username" and "currentUser.username"? I see where `ProfileProvider` is providing a `username` value. The sandbox code doesn't quite seem to align with what you are describing here.

Comment: The link I'm referring to is the one with the text: _Link to user2_ which navigates to `/user2`.  `username` is the variable inferred from the query parameter `:username`, i.e. username of the profile page we are currently on. By _currentUser.username_ , I'm referring to the username of the currently logged in user. In the sandbox it was the _user_ object with one prop: `username: tommy123`. I have now renamed this object to  `currentUser` . It is located in `ProfileProvider ` and used to determine if `visitor`.

I hope this clarifies things. Please let me know. And thanks for your time.

Comment: So `"tommy1234"` is the current user, and if we navigate to `"/tommy1234"` you want the app to redirect to `"/profile"`? Otherwise stay on whatever `"/:username"` is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249262/discussion-between-andyoh-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are separate routes each rendering their own `ProfileProvider`, so navigating between them each has their own state and logic independent of the other.

If what you really want is for the `Profile` component to compare the current authenticated user's username against the `username` route path parameter then move the `const { username } = useParams()` logic from the `ProfileProvider` component into the `Profile` component.

Example:

App - Move the `ProfileProvider` to wrap the routes.

```
<ProfileProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path=":username/*" element={<Profile />} />
    <Route path="profile/*" element={<Profile />} />
  </Routes>
</ProfileProvider>
```

Profile

```
export const Profile = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { username: currentUser } = useContext(ProfileContext);

  const { username } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser === username) {
      navigate("/profile", { replace: true });
    }
  }, [currentUser, navigate, username]);

  const text = username ? username : "Current User";

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Profile of:</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>{text}</p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-redirected-on-left-click-but-not-on-right-click]

Comment: Moving the logic to `Profile` works. However, if the problem stems from the two components having each their own context, fixing that seems the better approach. 
I see one problem though; there are several other routes in `App` which I don't wish to wrap in `ProfileProvider`. How can I achieve wrapping `/profile `and `/:username` in the same context provider with that in mind?

Comment: Looks like the solution to wrapping some, but not all, routes is a layout route, as described by you @Drew:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764023/how-do-i-wrap-2-routes-with-a-context-in-react-router-v6

Comment: It didn't solve the original problem, so I will stick with having the logic in `Profile`. It did however, solve the routing issue. The two routes now share context and readability is improved.

Comment: @AndyOh Great, sounds like this answer was able to mostly resolve your question/issue, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!