# How to pass data from one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have two js files, including login and sidebar.

In the login.js(class component), it will call the loginAction to perform an API call and get back response data(id, role, username).

```
  import LoginAction from auth.js
  ...
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    var response = LoginAction(this.state)
  }
```

LoginAction is in the auth.js

```
export function LoginAction(data) {
    const loginName = data.loginName;
    const password = data.password;

    var response = Login(loginName, password).then(response => {
        if (response.data.errorCode === "") {
            sessionStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.token)
            return {passwordError: null, loginNameError: null, isLoggedOn: true, role: response.data.data.isAdmin};
        } else {
            return formatError(response.data);
        }
    })
    return response;
};
```

Here is the Login which is in the authservice.js

```
export const Login = (loginName, password) => {
    const postData = { loginName, password }
    console.log(postData);

    return Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", postData, header);
}
```

how to pass the response to sidebar.js(class component)? I want to display the user's role on the sidebar.

```
if (data.isLoggedOn) {
        console.log("routing to /employee")
        this.props.router.navigate("/employee", { state: { "id": id, "role": role } })
      }
```

I have tried to use the state to pass the data, but the role cannot be loaded to the sidebar after the first loading. The role only displays when I load the sidebar page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a state in a common parent component and pass down a function that sets that state. Here's a quick example where I define a state `user` in the App and define `login()` which sets its state. Then I pass `login()` as a prop to the login button, and pass `user` as a prop to the sidebar.
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-darkness-y8iutd?file=/src/App.js:0-651)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {user: null}
  }

  login(user) {
    this.setState({user})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Login loginHandler={(user)=>this.login(user)}/>
      <Sidebar user={this.state.user}/>
    </div>
  );
}
}

class Sidebar extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div className="sidebar">Hey {this.props.user}</div>
      )
    }
} 

class Login extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={()=>this.props.loginHandler('Foo')}>Login</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: But the sidebar and login components are not on the same page.  When i click the login button, it will route to the next page which contains the sidebar. In this case, how can i pass the response data to the sidebar instead of directly passing the string that i assigned to it? @Brother58697

Comment: @manyProblem Ahh, from some research, it looks like the answer could lie in [contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: First time hearing about it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Anytime! Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907592/sharing-state-across-react-router-v6-routes-using-context-api) and the actual accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155909/how-to-use-context-api-with-react-router-v4)